# What is the most cost effective means of parking in NYC for 3-4 days

Tags: driving, new-york-city

I am planning a road trip to NYC. I am trying to determine how I should park. I plan on staying in Manhattan in central tourist area. I also plan on driving in, and not using my car until my stay is over (around 3-4 days).

What is the most cost effective means for parking my car for 3-4 days.

I do not need to access it again until I leave, and I will not be leaving valuables in it.

I will most likely be coming from the direction of Philadelphia.

I have considered either Hotel parking (which would be convenient but anticipate will be VERY expensive). Or I considered parking in an airport economy lot.

Comment: Please note you've asked a very broad question in your title, and then 3 separate questions in your question. This often leads to people closing a question as 'too broad', as per the rules in the [help]. I'd highly recommend editing your question to focus on a specific problem.

Comment: No, my trip includes stop in Washington DC, then Philly, then NYC, then home to Canada.

Comment: In that case, the only other suggestion I can make is to use [Waze](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.waze). :)

Comment: Are you due for oil change? If so, consider doing it in NYC: http://jalopnik.com/the-secret-to-cheap-and-safe-parking-for-a-tourist-in-n-1657972990 (probably won't work for 3-4 days though).

Comment: From experience with the parking cost in Manhattan, it might be cheapest to abandon the car and buy a new one afterwards...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't absolutely *need* your car in Manhattan, do yourself a favor and don't take your car into Manhattan. Driving there is not for the faint of heart, and parking fees are exorbitant.

Instead, park across the river in New Jersey and take the train in, like everyone else.

Consider stopping at one of several train stations along the [NJ Transit Northeast Corridor route](http://www.njtransit.com/pdf/rail/R0070.pdf), which runs roughly parallel to the New Jersey Turnpike, and parking in a parking lot or garage with cheap daily parking rates near the station.

Some likely looking stations are:

- [Princeton Junction](http://www.njtransit.com/rg/rg_servlet.srv?hdnPageAction=TrainStationLookupFrom&selStation=125&x=38&y=2): Parking from $5/day
- [Edison](http://www.njtransit.com/rg/rg_servlet.srv?hdnPageAction=TrainStationLookupFrom&selStation=38&x=42&y=9): Parking from $4/day
- [Metuchen](http://www.njtransit.com/rg/rg_servlet.srv?hdnPageAction=TrainStationLookupFrom&selStation=84&x=35&y=15): Parking from $5/day

There's sure to be inexpensive parking available elsewhere along the route into NYC, but these particular stations appear to have cheap parking available very near to the stations. Note that not all of the parking lots in these locations offer 24-hour parking, so check that you've parked in the right lot.

If you're unable to find parking at *any* of these stations, which is entirely possible, there are a number of [off-airport long-term parking areas around Newark Airport](http://www.airportparkingreservations.com/newark_airport_parking_ewr), from $7-$10 per day. These typically include a free shuttle to and from the airport terminal, from where you can catch the train into Manhattan.