# Is the Jersey City Port Imperial parking garage likely to be full during the summer?

Tags: automobiles, new-york-city, new-jersey

I am planning a summer trip to Manhattan. I will be driving in.

My current favourite parking solution would be to park at [Port Imperial ferry terminal](http://www.nywaterway.com/IndoorParkingGarage.aspx), and then take the ferry over. That way I would not have to bring my car into Manhattan, and I would get off the ferry near midtown, and have tonnes of hotels to select from.

So all I am really concerned about, is whether it is common place for this parking garage to fill up. Is it even a remote possibility? Timeframe is roughly July/August.

Comment: Related: [What is the most cost effective means of parking in NYC for 3-4 days](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/65901/3221)

Comment: It is always a possibility there is really no way to know given it's a vacation season.

Comment: This is true. Hopefully someone knows the tendencies of this particular garage.

Comment: Around Noon on a weekday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was not close to full, when I went in the summer. I asked the attendant, and she said they are never full.

So the answer is no, it is not likely to be full. It is in fact very very unlikely.

Answer (score 4):

Port Imperial isn't in Jersey City, it's in Weehawken.
Ferries to Manhattan run from multiple locations including Hoboken, Jersey City and Weehawken, additionally all these towns and the ferry terminals are connected with the [Hudson-Bergen Light Rail](https://www.njtransit.com/pdf/LightRail/sf_lr_hblr_map.pdf); should you need to hop from one place to the other.

If you are willing to be flexible in terms of the places where you are willing to park, then you needn't worry.
There are plenty of parking garages in Downtown Jersey City and Hoboken where you will be able to find parking and then take a ferry. (For completeness there is also the PATH system which connects both these places to Midtwon and Downtown Manhattan)

That said, I'm not sure why you'd want to park so close to Manhattan. Depending on where you are driving in from it may be more cost effective if you park at a [NJ Transit Park and Ride station](http://www.njtransit.com/rg/rg_servlet.srv?hdnPageAction=TrainStationLookupFrom&selStation=148&x=42&y=13) and take a train into Penn Station NY which is in Midtown. NJ Transit runs high speed trains that connects some of the NJ suburbs to Manhattan, most of these stations offer the Park and Ride option whereby you can park your car on the Parking Lot in the station and then take the train into the City. This is a good option because the traffic during peak hours on the roads into New York is almost always clogged up. While searching for a Park and Ride station be sure to check if it allows for overnight parking if you intend to leave your car there overnight.

Comment: Good answer. But could you elaborate on the last paragraph? What is a New Jersey Park and Ride Station?

Comment: @ScottF A NJ Transit Park and Ride station is a NJ Transit train station with parking. You park at one (as suggested here, ensure it allows overnight parking if you need that) and then ride the train into Manhattan.